# Let $\alpha\cot x+\beta\cot y+\gamma\cot z=\psi$ then find the minimum value of $\cot^2x+\cot^2y+\cot^2z$

Tags: inequality, trigonometry, contest-math, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

**Question:**

Let $\alpha\cot x+\beta\cot y+\gamma\cot z=\psi$ then the minimum value of $\cot^2x+\cot^2y+\cot^2z$ is

A) $\frac{\psi}{\alpha+\beta+\gamma}$

B) $\frac{\psi^2}{\alpha^2+\beta^2+\gamma^2}$

C) $\frac{|\psi|}{\sqrt{\alpha^2+\beta^2+\gamma^2}}$

D) $\psi\sqrt{\alpha^2+\beta^2+\gamma^2}$

**My Attempt:**

I first thought of weighted AM-GM inequality but couldn't conclude.

Then I squared the given equation and tried AM-GM inequality pairwise on the three terms, still couldn't conclude.

Then I took $\alpha=\beta=\gamma=1$ and $x=y=z=\frac\pi4$ then I got option B. Not sure if it is correct.

What's the proper way to solve it?

Comment: By Cauchy-Schwarz, $|\psi|\le\dots$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By C-S $$\sum_{cyc}\cot^2x\sum_{cyc}\alpha^2\geq\left(\sum_{cyc}\alpha\cot{x}\right)^2$$ and from here
$$\sum_{cyc}\cot^2x\geq\frac{\psi^2}{\alpha^2+\beta^2+\gamma^2}.$$
The equality occurs, when
$$\left(\cot{x},\cot{y},\cot{z}\right)||(\alpha,\beta,\gamma),$$ which says that we got a minimal value.